# I want to include an If statement in my SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, sql-server-2012

I have this insert statement I wrote, but I want to test for null before I insert data into the database> Below is the code

```
use master
DECLARE @PriviledgeID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @UserName uniqueidentifier 

SELECT @PriviledgeID=roleId 
FROM aspnet_Roles 
WHERE RoleName = 'Operator'

SELECT @UserName=USERID
FROM aspnet_Users
WHERE username = ments@point.com'


INSERT INTO aspnet_UsersInRoles
 VALUES(@UserName, @PriviledgeID )
```

My aim is to make sure I don't insert values of null into the database, how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: A suitable primary key or check constraint is the easier way, in my opinion.

Comment: this should be UI or business layer Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO aspnet_UsersInRoles
SELECT roleId, USERID 
  FROM aspnet_Roles  
 cross join aspnet_Users
 where RoleName = 'Operator'
   and username = 'ments@point.com' 
   and roleId is not null 
   and USERID is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this check first:

```
IF (@UserName IS NOT NULL AND @PriviledgeID IS NOT NULL)
   INSERT INTO aspnet_UsersInRoles
   VALUES(@UserName, @PriviledgeID )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I was looking for.